# ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression error when case statement accesses a function from a package

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Despite the fact that the cf_type column is the exact copy of the group by clause, I get ORA-00979 error:

```
select case when a.accdef in (select column_value from 
                            table(accounts.get_corr_asset_accs)) 
                          then 'IN' else 'OUT' end cf_type
from a
group by case when a.accdef in 
         (select column_value 
          from table(accounts.get_corr_asset_accs)) then 'IN' else 'OUT'

         end;
```

But in the following example, when the package is not accessed sql statement executes successfully:

```
select case when a.accdef in (select 1 from dual) then 'IN' else 'OUT' end cf_type
from a
group by case when a.accdef in (select 1 from dual) then 'IN' else 'OUT' end;
```

Why do I get the error(I know that I can use an inline view, but I'm more interested in the reason of error)?  Function(part of accounts package) and nested table definitions are as follows:

```
function get_corr_asset_accs return acc_numbers result_cache;

create type acc_numbers as table of number;
```

Comment: @Sachu, you provided an invalid edit. SQL statements should be in code format.

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping it like this:

```
select cf_type from (
select case when a.accdef in (select column_value from 
                        table(accounts.get_corr_asset_accs)) 
                      then 'IN' else 'OUT' end cf_type
from a
) group by cf_type;
```

Comment: I know about the workaround, I am interested in why do I get the error in the first place?

Comment: It's because it's non-deterministic, meaning given a single input (in this case nothing) it can give many different outputs.  Oracle knows this and it flags it.  If you believe the function IS deterministic, add this flag right before the "IS" in your function def and try again: DETERMINISTIC

Comment: I did mark it as deterministic, but I still got the error.

Comment: Ok that means the function is not actually deterministic, and won't work unless you capture the result set at an intermediary point.  This is what the outer select does.  I hope this answers your question?

Comment: How is it not deterministic if I explicitly marked it as deterministic? Maybe, the problem is that I am returning a user defined type.. need to check this.

Comment: Because the table itself could change and the function wouldn't know... that's the definition of deterministic.